# Validating a string rather than character set

Tags: regex

I'm validating user input, but it fails because it checks for any character in the character set as well.

How to assure that I can accept URI like:

```
e/1test1
page1/2test2
p/3test3
pag/4test4
test/63tedddddst/test5
```

but not when 'page' exist as a first word followed by '/':

```
page/test7
```

The expression:

```
^([^page].+?\/?)$
```

https://regex101.com/r/zP0tQ3/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a negative lookahead:

```
^(?!page\/).+$
```

[**Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/yE5aI8/4)

Comment: Sorry, I only need to skip only when this is at the begging 'page'. I didn't specify it in the OP.

Comment: I did. I hope it makes bit more sense now.

Comment: I think you just want to trigger the lookahead at start `^(?!page\/).*$`

Comment: I would write it as: `^(?!page/).+$` otherwise it will match an empty line.